# How do I cope with "spikes" in voice over

Tags: compression, limiters

A speaker sent me totally unprocessed voice over recording.

In this recoring, one can see "spikes".

[image]

What is the usual way to deal with these?

Thank you!

Comment: What are they? Are they speech pops into the mic, or electronic 'crackle'?

Comment: These are speech pops ("t" sounds)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to deal with this kind of things:

1. The one I would go with: send it back to the speaker and say that it is unusable and he has to make a better recording. Do help in setting up equipment and room and such better.
2. Use specialized tools: plugins for handling scratches in copied vinyl recordings might be something to look for. Izotope RX (expensive but good) is one example with a number of different tools that might help.
3. Painstakingly edit samples: open in your audio program, zoom into the wave form and edit the samples that are off to get a nice sound. Been there, done that: gray hairs to show for it.
4. Use the plugins you have: eq, limiters, compressors, de-essers, whatever. Might be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

This is of necessity vague. Without actually hearing it, it's hard to say with any precision.
Compression may remove the worst of it, multi-band compression may allow you to fine-tune to those frequencies.

Some training & technique might go towards avoiding the issue in future, correct distance, pop-shielding - though I've never known any decent mic make that kind of spike on sibilants, it's usually the plosives, P & B etc.